# issues installing karma,jasmine and phantomjs with npm in ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create angular project using yeomen.I installed grunt-cli,bower,angular-generator as explained in yeomen site.But the grunt build is unsuccessful throwing the following unmet dependency errors.

```
npm WARN EPEERINVALID grunt-karma@0.12.1 requires a peer of karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.2 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.2 requires a peer of phantomjs@>=1.9 but none was installed.
```

I tried installing the unmet dependencies as `npm install -g karma@^0.13.0`  and the installation was successful.
Here is the trace in terminal.

```
srinivas@srinivas-Vostro-3500:~/workspace/cord-angApp$ npm install -g karma@^0.13.0
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
/home/srinivas/.node/bin/karma -> /home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/bufferutil/build'

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/srinivas/.node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
/home/srinivas/.node/lib
`-- karma@0.13.16
```

After this i tried the `npm install` and could see the same error message.I think it is problem with node modules configuration path?

Answer (score 1):

Since i installed phantomjs,karma and jasmine globally like `npm install -g karma@` it was not installed locally.So i simply installed it without -g option `npm install karma` and this resolved the issue.